# omniture drupal s.prop showing previous track data

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, adobe-analytics

```
jQuery('selector1').click(function() {
    s.prop3 = 'loremmmmm';
    s.events = 'event11';
    s.tl();

});

jQuery('selector2').click(function() {
    s.prop14 = 'lorem isam';
    s.events = 'event32';
    s.tl();

});
```

`trying to track multiple prop and events when tracking one prop say s.prop2 = "";
and **s.prop3 = ""**. 
in this case getting value of s.prop3 also while tracking s.prop4 value it is not emptying the previous prop values any suggestion thanks in advance

Comment: if someone can help thanksin advance omniture

Answer (score 1):

Overall, your code should be changed to the following, **but before you change it, please read my notes below**, which explains the changes and the implications of them, versus what you have now.

```
jQuery('selector1').click(function() {
    s.prop3 = 'loremmmmm';
    s.events = 'event11';
    s.linkTrackVars='prop3,events';
    s.linkTrackEvents='event11';
    s.tl(true,'o','selector1 clicks');
});

jQuery('selector2').click(function() {
    s.prop14 = 'lorem isam';
    s.events = 'event32';
    s.linkTrackVars='prop14,events';
    s.linkTrackEvents='event32';
    s.tl(true,'o','selector2 clicks');
});
```

**Firstly, a definition of Adobe Analytics (AA) "trigger" methods.**

`s.t()` - This is meant for "page view" tracking, what you normally use to trigger AA calls when a page is first loaded. Data collected will count as a page view in reports. AA variables that have values when this gets called will be included in the http request.

`s.tl()` - This is meant for click (interaction) tracking, what you normally use to track link clicks or other interactions *after* a page is loaded. This will *not* count as a page view in your reports. Only variables and events that are set *and registered in* `linkTrackVars` and `linkTrackEvents` will be included in the http request. Note: other variables that are set are still there and in the cache; they just won't be included in the http request. So, think of `linkTrackVars` and `linkTrackEvents` as whitelists for the `s.tl` call.

**Variable caching**

AA "caches" variables that are explicitly set (e.g. `s.prop1='foo';`). Those variables continue to exist with their values for any subsequent `s.t()` or `s.tl()` call you make on the same page (it does not carry over from page to page via cookies).

**Your current code**

When you call `s.tl()` with no arguments passed, AA treats it as if `s.t()` were called, so any AA variables or events (assuming you don't overwrite them) already set will be included in the http request, even if they aren't "registered" in `linkTrackVars` and `linkTrackEvents`. **This is the immediate reason why your variables are carried over**. However, I want to also point out the fact that your code is also effectively counting these click interactions as page views, which is *probably* not what you intended.

**What the new code does**

The new code I have shown is under the assumption that you don't actually want these clicks to count as page views. So, I have added `linkTrackVars` and `linkTrackEvents` to "register" the events and variables.

Also notice how I added some arguments to `s.tl`. The first argument is traditionally a reference to the link that was clicked (e.g. in the click callback, where `this` is a reference to the link that was clicked, you would pass `this` as the first argument to `s.tl`.  However, not all interactions on a site are actual links, and `s.tl` only works if the first argument is either a reference to an actual link object (more accurately, something with an href attribute), or boolean `true`. Also, the reason for passing it was for a legacy ClickMap feature that's always been buggy and is no longer supported by Adobe anyways. So, I always just pass `true`.

The second argument specifies what type of link or interaction it is. There are 3 available values: "d" (signifying download is initiated),"e" (specifying an exit from the site), and "o" ("other" - a general "catch-all" bucket). I don't know the context of these event handlers you have, so I just used "o". Feel free to use one of the other values if you feel they are more appropriate.

The 3rd argument is a string value to describe the link/interaction; a "label". *Generally* you should use something short but descriptive of the event that occurred, but honestly, *most* people don't really look at the native link reports in AA interface because they are basically useless as far as breaking it down or associating it with downstream activities. Which is why most people pop custom `events`, `props`, and `eVars`, and look at those reports, instead. So, more than likely you can just put some static, generic "click/interaction" type value (you *must* pop 3rd arg with *something*) and call it a day.

**If you did indeed intend to count these as page views**

- Remove `linkTrackVars` and `linkTrackEvents` lines.
- Remove the `s.tl(..)` calls and replace with `s.t()` (no arguments).
- This is where it gets tricky - you must explicitly wipe any AA variables you do not wish to be part of the hit. You can set them to an empty string or `delete` them.

On that 3rd point, as you have probably guessed, that's a pain point. There are some easier workarounds for this, but I don't know the full context of your implementation to know if they are good options for you (or even available options).

For example, AA does have a `s.clearVars()` method but it is only available in (relatively) recent versions of the AppMeasurement library. So if you are still on the legacy H code library, or on one of the earlier versions of AppMeasurement, then this method won't be available. If it is available in your library version, then just call that first (no arguments). Then set your variables and `s.t()` call.

If `s.clearVars()` is not available to you, you can of course just define your own method. Essentially, `s.clearVars()` just loops through and deletes or sets empty string to all propN and eVarN variables, as well as most of the named AA variables (pageName, channel, events, etc.). Same thing as above: first call it to wipe the vars, then set the new ones and then trigger.

Depending on what version of AA code you use, it is possible to pass AA vars as an object payload (e.g. `{prop1:'foo',events:'event'}` as an argument to `s.t()` and `s.tl()` and they will only count for that http request and afterwards be wiped. But there are a number of things quirks/caveats to consider if you want to go this route, which is a whole other TL;DR. I suggest you read the online AA documentation about the `s.t` and `s.tl` methods for details.